Brownian motion $B_t$ and $\int_0^t\mathrm{sgn}(B_s)dB_s$ equal in distribution
I am reading a paper about local time and the running maximum of Brownian motions. Let $B$ be a Brownian motion and $L^x_t$ its local time. By Tanaka's formula, we have $$|B_t|=\int_0^t\mathrm{sgn}(B_s)dB_s+L^0_t=\tilde{B_t}+L_t^0,$$
where we know that $\tilde{B}_t:=\int_0^t\mathrm{sgn}(B_s)dB_s$ is a Brownian motion. Moreover, by Skorohod theory it follows that $L^0_t=\sup_{s\leq t}\tilde{B}^{-}_t$, hence
$$|B_t|=\tilde{B_t}+\sup_{s\leq t}\tilde{B}^{-}_t$$
It was said, that $\tilde{B}\overset{d}{=}B$, i.e. they are equal in distribution. How can I prove this?
Thanks for your help.

Compute the quadratic variation.

See page 91 in these lecture notes for an explanation.
